# Is there a way to see CPU usage for a specific clickhouse query

Tags: clickhouse

I'm testing a query and want to see how much CPU it will use.

I know I can use [systems.query_log](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_log/) to get some useful info on query performance, but it does not have any info about CPU usage.

Is there a way to get CPU usage other than running `top` on my clickhouse server and watching the `%CPU` while I run my query?

Answer (score 3):

It does have -- ProfileEvents: UserTimeMicroseconds + SystemTimeMicroseconds

```
select any(query), sum(`ProfileEvents.Values`[indexOf(`ProfileEvents.Names`, 'UserTimeMicroseconds')]) userCPU from system.query_log 
where type = 2 and event_date >= today()
group by normalizedQueryHash(query)
order by userCPU desc
limit 10
```